# Not able to search the data in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I need to search by Suburb however it does not return anything even though there's a data. Here is the stored procedure implementation and I have added it in the where statement. Please help me what cause the issue. Thank you.

```
WHERE
        ((@DriverId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') OR
        (@DriverId IS NULL AND tl.T_DriverId IS NULL) OR
        (@DriverId IS NOT NULL AND tl.T_DriverId = @DriverId)) AND
        ((@SearchBySuburb IS NOT NULL AND @Suburb = 0 AND pa.A_Suburb = @SearchBySuburb) AND
        (@SearchBySuburb IS NOT NULL AND @Suburb = 1 AND da.A_Suburb = @SearchBySuburb)) AND
        ((@HideCompleted = 1 AND @StatusId = 0 AND tl.T_Status != 8) OR
        (@HideCompleted = 1 AND @StatusId = 0 AND tl.T_Status IS NULL) OR
        (@HideCompleted = 1 AND @StatusId > 0 AND tl.T_Status = @StatusId) OR
        (@HideCompleted = 0 AND @StatusId = 0) OR
        (@HideCompleted = 0 AND @StatusId > 0 AND tl.T_Status = @StatusId)) AND
        (@OrganizationId IS NULL OR o.O_ID = @OrganizationId) AND
        ((@StartDate IS NULL AND tl.T_PlannedDeliveryDate IS NULL) OR (@EndDate IS NULL AND tl.T_PlannedDeliveryDate IS NULL) OR (tl.T_PlannedDeliveryDate BETWEEN CAST(@StartDate AS DATE) AND CAST(@EndDate AS DATE)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The only time you use @SearchBySuburb is in the following fragment

```
((@SearchBySuburb IS NOT NULL AND @Suburb = 0 AND pa.A_Suburb = @SearchBySuburb) AND
 (@SearchBySuburb IS NOT NULL AND @Suburb = 1 AND da.A_Suburb = @SearchBySuburb))
```

Given they're all `AND`, that part cannot ever evaluate as true because you're checking if `@Suburb = 0 AND @Suburb = 1`.

I suggest being very explicit with brackets and checking your ANDs and ORs.

---

**Update following OP's comment about it still not working**

I've re-formatted your WHERE into conceptual groups separated by AND clauses- see below. The groups are broadly about the driver, suburb, status, organisation, and start/end dates.

My suggestion is to
a) Start with none of them (which should therefore show all rows)
b) Add the groups (separated by ANDs) to the WHERE clause one at a time until your desired rows disappear

When your desired rows disappear, it tells you there's a problem with the last added filters to the WHERE clause.

```
WHERE
    (
        (@DriverId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') 
        OR (@DriverId IS NULL AND tl.T_DriverId IS NULL) 
        OR (@DriverId IS NOT NULL AND tl.T_DriverId = @DriverId)
    ) 
AND 
    (
        (@SearchBySuburb IS NOT NULL AND @Suburb = 0 AND pa.A_Suburb = @SearchBySuburb) 
        OR (@SearchBySuburb IS NOT NULL AND @Suburb = 1 AND da.A_Suburb = @SearchBySuburb)
    ) 
AND 
    (
        (@HideCompleted = 1 AND @StatusId = 0 AND tl.T_Status != 8) 
        OR (@HideCompleted = 1 AND @StatusId = 0 AND tl.T_Status IS NULL) 
        OR (@HideCompleted = 1 AND @StatusId > 0 AND tl.T_Status = @StatusId) 
        OR (@HideCompleted = 0 AND @StatusId = 0) 
        OR (@HideCompleted = 0 AND @StatusId > 0 AND tl.T_Status = @StatusId)
    ) 
AND
    (@OrganizationId IS NULL OR o.O_ID = @OrganizationId) 
AND
    (
        (@StartDate IS NULL AND tl.T_PlannedDeliveryDate IS NULL) 
        OR (@EndDate IS NULL AND tl.T_PlannedDeliveryDate IS NULL) 
        OR (tl.T_PlannedDeliveryDate BETWEEN CAST(@StartDate AS DATE) AND CAST(@EndDate AS DATE))
    )
```

Comment: Even if changing it to OR still no result

Comment: Without knowing what you're trying to do, what your data looks like, expected results etc -  it's impossible for anyone to determine why it is still giving no result - so it's up to you to find the issue. However, I've updated my answer with a suggested approach.

Comment: I agree with @seanb. To debug, you could try commenting out individual statements in the where clause. When you see the records you arent currently seeing, you will know that it was that statement that what hiding those records. Obviously that statement would have been there for a reason, so you just need to find another way of expressing that statement so that it filters out the intended records without filtering out the ones you are looking for. good luck.

Comment: This really helps. Thank you so much. I've found the issue and fixed it.